Running Tests Across Multiple Repositories from a Single Test Directory
I’m currently working on a website with a somewhat complex architecture, which is structured as follows:
REPO-A
  /.git
  /files
  /SUB-REPO
    /.git
    /files
REPO-B
  /.git
  /files

My technical manager has tasked me with implementing continuous integration for this project. However, I’m just starting to learn Devops.
We’re using PHPUnit 10.5 and PHP 8.1, and we host our repositories on GitLab.
The challenge I’m facing is that I’ve been asked to manage the tests from a single test directory within a single project, despite the architecture spreading across multiple repositories. I believe this is an unusual requirement for a non-standard architecture, which is why I’m seeking advice.
My Questions:

How can I automate these tests using GitLab CI pipelines across this setup? Is it possible to have a single YAML file in one repository that triggers all the automated tests for each push in all repositories?

Is this approach considered a bad practice? If so, could you explain why?




Is this approach considered a bad practice? If so, could you explain why?

There is no approach yet with practice, therefore considering it bad or good would keep the doing out of practice which is not bad practice, it is just no practice at all. The worst you are able to achieve.
Therefore apart from asking - which you're free to and should practice always - there is no (bad) practice yet.
Quite the opposite, lets look on the existing structure of git repositories as you have outlined it in your question. We took the freedom to compact it, and hope it remains clear in context of your question:
REPO-A
        SUB-REPO
REPO-B

You have the requirement to control this from one repository, using multiple repositories and sub repositories is per the requirements and the good, known practice.
Therefore, if not yet done for whatever reason, apply this good practice first, and first of all create the training ground to become more fluent with Git sub projects as already practiced and root-into that known, good, and required practice:
[.git]
[.gitmodules]
REPO-A
        SUB-REPO
REPO-B

---

[.git]: https://git-scm.com/docs/ "`git --fast-version-control` Reference"
[.gitmodules]: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitsubmodules "gitsubmodules - Mounting one repository inside another"

With that out of the door, let's see what is challenging:

The challenge I’m facing is that I’ve been asked to manage the tests from a single test directory within a single project, despite the architecture spreading across multiple repositories.

Done. Look above. Repeat, as long as it becomes crystal clear. Git is documented. Do, Read, Demo, Repeat.

I believe this is an unusual requirement for a non-standard architecture, which is why I’m seeking advice.

Git has sub projects as well as sub modules to manage them since a very, very long time. We have a hard time to imagine that this could be an unusual requirement.
However, Git is much older than Gitlab. So, better safe than sorry, luck is with the prepared and let's verify if the software to manage the VCS repositories supports the VCS and it was not just some marketing!
The software to manage the VCS is GitLab, and specifically it is here about the Gitlab CI/CD offerings.
[.gitmodules]: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/git_submodules.html "Using Git submodules with GitLab CI/CD"

Done. Look above. Repeat, as long and as often until it becomes crystal clear.
GitLab is documented. Do, Read, Demo, Repeat.

Now after all those clarifications:
You have asked two questions, with the second one we started, but the first one is still open.
We took the liberty to switch the order. As Git is leading GitLab, an answer would be far too error prone if there would not yet be best practice with the existing use of Git. Your best practice with GitLab can only ever be as good as the practice with Git already is.
So, are you feeling ready now for an answer to the first question?

How can I automate these tests using GitLab CI pipelines across this setup? Is it possible to have a single YAML file in one repository that triggers all the automated tests for each push in all repositories?

If you use Git for software configuration management from the root, from the ground upwards, and you use the .gitlab-ci.yml YAML file in that one repository to have the configuration you're looking for, you can not only run the tests using GitLab CI pipelines, you can use GitLab CI pipelines to manage and configure the whole.
So therefore, yes, you can use a single .gitlab-ci.yml to run the shop. Even none (, or close to none, auto-devops.)
The boundaries in GitLab CI/CD are pretty lax by the way. For example IIRC the limits on components is 30 in a row. Just to show another option. But hold on the wild horses, don't burn your options already in the beginning.
Instead have a local demo of the git repository twice a day at minimum from the beginning. Talk with all the developers early in the morning, present before lunch. Then demo again before leave. The next morning you then talk again with all the developers. Do, Read, Demo, Repeat. Until this is crystal clear for all the developers in the affected group.
Managing repositories with a software designed for that is piece of cake.
Getting this to run by people is hard work. Your job is to run the bakery, so that others can bake cakes over and over again.

Thank you for your thoughtful answer and the effort you put into it. As a young computer science student, I truly appreciate the advice. I'm not fluent in English, so it might take me a bit of time to thoroughly read and fully understand your response. I haven't had the time to implement it yet, but I will make sure to accept it a soon as possible if it resolves my problem.

Ca rule @Kolobo, merci beaucoup. Start with git init in a new directory. Then add your Gitlab instance as the remote named "origin" (command: git remote add ...) and then push it git push. Then touch .gitlab-ci.yml, git commit .gitlab-ci.yml and again git push. now call glab ci status. if that command is not yet found, install it. You eventually then come to the point where you would like to add the first git submodule. do it, then follow up with one submodule after the other.
